# Validate a file extension using getMimeType

Tags: 8, forms

I want to create a hook that will validate a file upload and only allow jpg extension or a multiple array jpg, gif. I am not sure how to do this. If this  below can validate the length of the file title.

```
if (strlen($file
 ->getFilename()) > 100) {
    $errors[] = t("The file's name exceeds the 100 characters limit.");
 }
```

Then can something simular to this work?

```
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
 function blank_moda_file_validate(Drupal\file\FileInterface $file) {
   $errors = array();

if ($file
 ->getMimeType()) !== jpg, gif) {
   $errors[] = t("The file is not a jpg or gif.");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [file_validate_extensions()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21file%21file.module/function/file_validate_extensions/8.3.x) for this

Comment: I saw the example for  hook_validate_extensions() inside: /core/modules/file/file.module, line 336. And here:https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21file%21file.module/function/file_validate_extensions/8.3.x  But I do not know how to alter the function to specifically allow only jpg and gif.

Comment: The second argument to file_validate_extensions() is an array of file extensions that are allowed.